# Зачем нужна ф-я save() в IdiORM

Tags: php, orm, idiorm

Изучаю idiorm и не могу понять зачем в примере на выборку используется функция save()

```
$people = ORM::for_table('person')->find_many();
foreach ($people as $person) {
    $person->age = 50; 
    $person->save();
}
```

И как получить строку запроса в idiorm?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что это только на выборку? ну это на выборку `и не только`. Чуйка подсказывает что вы в `$people` делаете выборку а потом в `foreach` вы делаете апдейт, полученных значений, изменяя их возраст на 50, для этого и нужен `save()`

Comment: Не знаком с этой орм,  но по коду смею предположить,  что каждому человеку присваивается возраст равняющийся 50. Для этого и метод save

Comment: Да в документации так указано